# tabChange event on primefaces tabView doesn't set values in ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing a problem using primefaces 5.0 and jsf 2.2.5. Using a 
 `p:tabView`  with two tabs sharing the same ManagedBean and the same object the event  `tabChange` is not working as expected. When user change the tab I want to execute the same validation as if he had clicked the button, but the event is not refreshing the bean values, however the values are being posted. I was able to reproduce the problem with this simple example.
xhtml code:

```
<h:body>
    <div class="well">
        <h:form id="testeForm">
            <p:tabView id="tView">
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" 
                        process="@this" 
                        update="@form"
                        listener="#{testeBean.onTabChange}" />
                <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1">
                    <p:inputText id="teste1" 
                                 value="#{testeBean.evento.nome}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="savetab1" 
                                     process="tab1" 
                                     update="@form"
                                     actionListener="#{testeBean.saveTab1}" 
                                     value="salvarTab1">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2">
                    <p:inputText id="teste2" 
                                 value="#{testeBean.evento.descricao}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="savetab2" 
                                     process="tab2" 
                                     update="@form"
                                     actionListener="#{testeBean.saveTab2}" 
                                     value="salvarTab2">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

ManagedBean:

```
package com.example.bean;
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "testeBean")
@Getter
@Setter
public class TesteBean {

private Evento evento;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    evento = new Evento();
}
public void saveTab1() {
    System.out.println(evento);
}

public void saveTab2() {
    System.out.println(evento);
}

public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent evt) throws LoundScreenException {
    System.out.println(evt.getTab().getId());
    System.out.println(evento);
}
```

}

The value being posted:
[image: inputText posted]

I tried  `process="@this" process="@form" process="@all" immediate="true"`  without success. Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance.

**Important Update:**

After spent some time debugging primefaces code, in the class  `org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel`  I realize that Primefaces only processes child components in its process() methods if it is not the source of the ajax request:

```
if(isRequestSource(context)) {
   return;
}
```

So I remove this piece of code and recompile primefaces and now it works fine. I'll let this question open, just in case of someone more experienced than me find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
                  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" 
                  content="user-scalable=no, 
                  width=device-width, 
                  initial-scale=1.0, 
                  maximum-scale=1.0"/>
        </f:facet>

        <title>page2</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="testeForm">
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc" 
                             process="@this,tView:teste1,tView:teste2" 
                             update="tView:teste1,tView:teste2" 
                             actionListener="#{testeBean.execute}" />
            <p:tabView id="tView" onTabChange="rc()">
                <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1">
                    <p:inputText id="teste1" 
                                 value="#{testeBean.evento.nome}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="savetab1" 
                                     process="tab1" 
                                     update="@form"
                                     actionListener="#{testeBean.saveTab1}" 
                                     value="salvarTab1">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2">
                    <p:inputText id="teste2" 
                                 value="#{testeBean.evento.descricao}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="savetab2" 
                                     process="tab2" 
                                     update="@form"
                                     actionListener="#{testeBean.saveTab2}" 
                                     value="salvarTab2">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

managedbean

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
/**
 *
 * @author Wittakarn
 */
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "testeBean")
public class TesteBean implements Serializable{

    private Evento evento;

    public TesteBean(){
        evento = new Evento();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public void saveTab1() {
        System.out.println(evento.getNome());
        System.out.println(evento.getDescricao());
    }

    public void saveTab2() {
        System.out.println(evento.getNome());
        System.out.println(evento.getDescricao());
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println(evento.getNome());
        System.out.println(evento.getDescricao());
    }

    public Evento getEvento() {
        return evento;
    }

    public void setEvento(Evento evento) {
        this.evento = evento;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer once more. I get your point, but imagine a scenario where you have multiple tabs, and if a user is currently in tab3 and then the user click on tab1, so I have to validate the object fields that are on tab3 and if that's ok, go to tab1. That's why I need tabChange event, I need to know the source tab and next tab. Any other tip?

Answer (score 0):

After primefaces 6.0

```
<p:ajax event="*" listener="*" skipChildren="false">
```

**skipChildren="false"**

helps, and set value to managed beans before listener's function call.